# Online normalisation with matlab and DataAquisitionToolbox

Tags: matlab

I do have the following problem with online data acquisition in matlab. I want to logg a fixed number of 4096 samples, do my calculation and predict signal. I do get in online acquiring always the error:

```
Attempted to access logData(:,32); index out of bounds because
size(logData)=[128,31].

Error in ==> SA_CONT at 23
normData(:,k45) = logData(:,k45)/norm(logData(:,k45),2);

Error in ==> SA_callback at 44
if(SA_CONT(data,plotHandle,SVM_RBF_model))
```

AND HERE IS THE MISTAKE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

```
[normData] = zeros(size(logData));
for k45 = 1:length(logData)
    normData(:,k45) = logData(:,k45)/norm(logData(:,k45),2);
end
```

it would be realy nice if some one has a suggestion. If you could provide me with code would be even better!

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the condition of the loop to:

```
for k45 = 1:size(logData,2)
```

Comment: Yeah! worked! I'm not the big programmer. Thanks. Even though I still have serious timing problems :). Do you have by any chance, some ideas how i could improve timing issues, or do you see other oppertunities?!? would be as well a great help!

Comment: It is great that it worked! In order to keep SO in order, please accept this answer if it solved your problem, and start a new question to ask about timing optimization.